# is there any possible to send input as image file in Chat bot

Tags: bots, chatbot, microsoft-teams, power-virtual-agents

I'm using MS Teams application's latest version and i' creating a bot using power virtual agents and want to give the input as an image file to bot server. is there any way to create this?

**Default User Input**
[inputs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Mhr3T.png)

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Teams does not allow attachments by default. To send and receive files in the bot in teams, set the `supportsFiles` property in the manifest to `true`.

```
 "bots": [
    {
      "botId": "<<YOUR-MICROSOFT-APP-ID>>",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ],
      "supportsFiles": true
    }
  ]
```

Else create an app for your bot in App studio. Specify your app allows upload attachments. And install it in your own Team account for testing.

Please look at this [sample code](https://github.com/microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/main/samples/csharp_dotnetcore/56.teams-file-upload) for reference.

Comment: @MuthuMani - Does the above help clarify?